# Admob banner not working on iOS 8 and 9 (works fine on 7)

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, admob, ads

Banner ads (admob) don't seem to be working on iOS 8 and 9, but work fine on 7.

on iOS 8, Xcode gives me this error:

```
<Google> To get test ads on this device, call: request.testDevices =
@[ @"3edebae...c4e80bf" ];
```

This happens even if I request for real ads.
Both real ads and test ads are working on iOS 7, so this issue is only on 8 and 9.

Also found this admob consideration, but does not help.
https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/ios9

Any ideas what might be the issue here?

Thanks!